# Magento list products with selected options from multiselect

Tags: magento

In my module I have to get list of all products with selected options from multiselect...

Does anyone have collection query or example for this?

My code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('frustration_flags'); // multiple select attribute
        $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'frustration_flags','finset'=>array('FFL, FTG'))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok my solution is bellow but this get all products with any of selected value but i want products with all selected options.

```
$flag_filter = array( 
    array(
        "finset" => array('FFL')
    ),
    array(
        "finset" => array('FTG')
    )
);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('frustration_flags'); // multiple select attribute
$collection->addFieldToFilter('frustration_flags', $flag_filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('frustration_flags', array('in' => array('FFL', 'FTG')));
```